# Unable to push Data to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm new to React and MongoDB so I don't really know what to do about this. I'm building an attendance app for a fun little learning project and I'm at this stage where I don't really know what to do. I have a page full of text inputs for all of the parameters I've defined for the database, and each textbox has that assigned, and I've used Axios to push it to my MongoDB atlas server. It keeps giving me the below errors

`register failed`

*`AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}`*

**`code`**`: "ERR_NETWORK"`

**`config`**`: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}`

**`message`**`: "Network Error"`

**`name`**`: "AxiosError"`

**`request`**`: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}`

**`stack`**`: "AxiosError: Network Error\n at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo-router%5Centry.bundle//&platform=web&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:155099:16)\n at Axios.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo-router%5Centry.bundle//&platform=web&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:153392:47)\n at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)\n at asyncGeneratorStep (http://localhost:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo-router%5Centry.bundle//&platform=web&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:2510:26)\n at _throw (http://localhost:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo-router%5Centry.bundle//&platform=web&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:2532:11)"`

`[Prototype]]: Error`

And

```
POST http://localhost:7000/addEmployee net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Here's my code

```
const employeeData = {
      employeeID: employeeID,
      name: name,
      department: department,
      joiningDate: joiningDate,
      activeEmployee: true,
      phoneNumber: mobileNo,
      discordID: discordID,
    };

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:7000/addEmployee", employeeData)
      .then((response) => {
        Alert.alert(
          "Registration Successful",
          "You have been registered successfully"
        );
        setName("");
        setEmployeeId("");
        setMobileNo("");
        setDiscordID("");
        setJoiningDate("");
        setDesignation("");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Alert.alert(
          "Registration Fail",
          "An error occurred during registration"
        );
        console.log("register failed", error);
      });
```

I also get this from MongoDB driver

`(node:54960) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: useNewUrlParser is a deprecated option: useNewUrlParser has no effect since Node.js Driver version 4.0.0 and will be removed in the next major version`

`` (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) ``

`(node:54960) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: useUnifiedTopology is a deprecated option: useUnifiedTopology has no effect since Node.js Driver version 4.0.0 and will be removed in the next major version`

I don't really know what to do and was hoping someone could help me.